# Tensorflow: How do the gradients get incorporated into the trainable variables?

Tags: python, tensorflow, gradient

I am fairly new to TensorFlow. I am struggeling to understand how TF incorporates the gradients into the variables for LSTMs (when using a gradient decent optimizer).

When I call `tf.trainable_variables()` during the first iteration and `tf.gradients()`
 during the second iteration I should be able to calculate the `tf.trainable_variables()` of the second iteration right (by multiplying the gradient with the learning rate)?

As I understood the theory an updated weight is equal to the pre-updated weight minus the gradient of that weight (wrt the loss) times the learning rate. However when I do this for a BasicLSTM cell with a DynamicRNN this does not seem the case.

Comment: Actually, it depends on the optimization algorithm you are using. There are several ones like adam, adadelta, RMSProp, momentum...

Comment: Vanilla gradient descent works the way you described.

Comment: I am using the tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer as optimizer. This should be vanilla right?

Comment: indeed, it is the case.

Comment: please post the code so that we can clearly understand what you intend to do.